Leaflet base layer types
as a complete beginner to Leaflet, could someone assist with this query.
Is it possible to have a polygon as a base layer or must it be a tiled layer?
If tiled, what are the allowed projections? when not using any other usual tiled base layer.
Thanks,
Cosmo
I have searched for answers but found none.
